JSON Schema Validation - networknt json-schema-validator : How to use the custom meta-schema for validation
Iam creating a custom meta-schema json file by extending the existing json-schema version 202012. How can i make json-schema-validator to use this custom meta-schema instead of default schema dialect from 202012?
Problem details:
I have created a JSON file in my local called "my_custom_meta_schema.json" which has following content:

{

  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",

  "$id": "https://domain/meta-schema/myschema/v1/schema",

  "$vocabulary": {

    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/core": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/applicator": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/unevaluated": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/validation": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/meta-data": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/format-annotation": true,
    "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/vocab/content": true
  },
  "$dynamicAnchor": "meta",

  "title": "Core and Validation specifications meta-schema",
  "allOf": [
    {"$ref": "meta/core"},
    {"$ref": "meta/applicator"},
    {"$ref": "meta/validation"},
    {"$ref": "meta/format-annotation"},
    {"$ref": "meta/content"}
  ],
  "type": ["object", "boolean"],
  "properties": {
    "minDate": {
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "\\d\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d",
      "format": "date"
    }
  }

}


Now, I will be creating a schema which uses the above meta-schema , It will start with something like :
{
  "$schema": "https://domain/meta-schema/myschema/v1/schema",
  "$id": "https://domain/retail/product.schema",
   ...
}

I am using networknt's json-schema-validator
implementation ("com.networknt:json-schema-validator:1.4.0")
How can I make JsonSchemaFactory to use the custom meta schema instead of default one?
My current function uses default 202012 draft . but I want to use my custom meta schema (extended from 202012 version) for validation
My current function (It doesn't use custom meta schema currently ):
     fun validateData(jsonData: Map<String, Any>): List<String> {
               val  jsonSchemafactory : JsonSchemaFactory = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V202012)
               val config = SchemaValidatorsConfig()
               val objectMapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper()
               config.pathType = PathType.JSON_POINTER
               val jsonSchemaInputStream: InputStream = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:my_schema.json").inputStream
       
               val jsonNode: JsonNode = objectMapper.valueToTree(jsonData)
               val jsonSchema = jsonSchemafactory.getSchema(jsonSchemaInputStream)
               val validationResults = jsonSchema.validate(jsonNode)
               if (validationResults.isEmpty()) {
                   println("Validation successful")
               } else {
                   println("Validation failed")
               validationResults.forEach {
                  println(it.message)
                }
              }
             return validationResults.asSequence().map { it.message }.toList()
       }


